# Why shows error message when generating application release

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following problem, when generating the release of my application, it shows me this message, even though I add the libraries you need, that message still appears, also try using the windeployqt.exe and it does not work, any suggestion would be appreciated .

I am using version 5.15.2 of qt

[image]

Comment: Could you translate the error message to English please?  It could be that it can't open the .exe file for writing because the program is running.

Comment: monitoreo_xertek.exe - Entry point not found.

The procedure entry point _Z21qRegisterResourceDataiPKhSO_SO_ cannot be found in the dynamic link library.
D: \ QtProjects \ build-monitoring_xertek-Release \ release \ monitoring_xertek.exe

Comment: This likely means there is a different incompatible dll in the PATH with the same name

Comment: I tried creating a new project and in the same way I get that error, with version 5.15.2, but when I do the same with version 6.1.1 it creates the executable without any problem

Comment: I don' t use Qt on Windows, but on Mac, I would remove the ../build directory entirely and regenerate. Doing so solves a lot of these weird problems. May or may not help.

Comment: I already tried that but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem, I was checking in the advanced configuration of the system and it happened that it had several values, in the PATH variable with paths to the Qt installation folder, so I deleted them all and with that I could solve my problem, thanks for your answers.

now the problem is with respect to the database, I managed to generate the executable, add all the libraries you need, it happens that it does not show anything when I run it.
[image]

The application is already running, but the data is not displayed, which it queries from the DB.